# Multiple led fade using charlieplexing at Arduino

Tags: arduino, led

Fading single led using charlieplexing is simple ([example code](http://n00bsys0p.co.uk/blog/2012/07/09/charlieplexing-leds-arduino)).
Is it possible to fade all leds independently? (I would like to fade them all simultaneously and randomly with different periods using Arduino).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you could, but you have to re-write the logic of the fading.
Probably you should create an array to keep trace of the fading for each leds

int fade[] = {0,0,0}

Then on each loop you write on each analog the current fade for each position. Also, you will need to modify this array to increase or decrease the fading.